# AWS lambda puppeteer timed out when creating browser

Tags: aws-lambda, puppeteer, chromium, serverless

I am trying to run chromium browser instance inside Lambda using puppeteer and sparticuz/chromium. when I run Lambda gets timed out after 20 secs with 256MB of memory.

The dependencies are created as layer using cloud9 and is included in the lambda.

```
import chromium from '@sparticuz/chromium';
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-core';

export const handler = async (event,context) => {

  var exPath=await chromium.executablePath();
  console.log('exPath'+exPath);

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: chromium.args,
    defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
    executablePath: exPath,
    headless: false,
   });
  console.log("----browser created");
};
```

Response
{
"errorMessage": "2024-03-02T22:21:20.929Z c4ffd913-d40b-4029-b1f2-91971bbe177d Task timed out after 17.11 seconds"
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: c4ffd913-d40b-4029-b1f2-91971bbe177d Version: $LATEST
2024-03-02T22:21:20.389Z    c4ffd913-d40b-4029-b1f2-91971bbe177d
INFO    exPath/tmp/chromium
2024-03-02T22:21:20.929Z c4ffd913-d40b-4029-b1f2-91971bbe177d Task timed out after 17.11 seconds

END RequestId: c4ffd913-d40b-4029-b1f2-91971bbe177d
REPORT RequestId: c4ffd913-d40b-4029-b1f2-91971bbe177d  Duration: 17110.91 ms   Billed Duration: 17000 ms   Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 256 MB Init Duration: 816.57 ms

Request ID
c4ffd913-d40b-4029-b1f2-91971bbe177d

Comment: Is the Lambda function configured for VPC? If so, don't, unless you know why you're doing it.

Comment: `Max Memory Used: 256 MB`. Have you considered the possibility that 256mb is not enough memory to launch a chrome instance?

Comment: @apokryfos. thank you it did work after increasing the memory to 512 MB. I never thought it might go to 512 as I used the headless version.

Answer (score 0):

As @apokryfos suggested the memory required to run the chromium binary was high and increasing it to 512MB resolved the issue.